# Snow Leopard starts launchd for non-existent user

Tags: macos, launchd

Lately my OS X 10.6.6 system exhibited some weird behaviours. I started snooping around and noticed that launchctl lists an entry for a non-existent user:

```
bash-3.2# launchctl list|grep launchd
1       -       0x101801c10.anonymous.launchd
57656   -       com.apple.launchd.peruser.504
-       0       com.apple.launchd.peruser.26
-       0       com.apple.launchd.peruser.4294967294  <-- this line
-       0       com.apple.launchd.peruser.27
58565   -       com.apple.launchd.peruser.503
62936   -       com.apple.launchd.peruser.0
466     -       com.apple.launchd.peruser.501
22417   -       com.apple.launchd.peruser.502
-       0       com.apple.launchd.peruser.212
1       -       0x101801950.anonymous.launchd
-       0       com.apple.launchd.peruser.70
-       0       com.apple.bsd.launchdadd
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not non-existent, it's [`nobody`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_(username)):

```
id nobody
uid=4294967294(nobody) gid=4294967294(nobody)
```

Comment: And nobody is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_(username)

Comment: @Jamgold Don't forget to accept this answer with a checkmark if it answers your question!

Comment: @NReilingh Doah, I never noticed the checkmark and was always trying to click the useful arrow ...